# How do I fix invalid filename extension?

Tags: apt, updates, extension, filename

```
Ignoring file 'sublime-text.lis' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

Comment: What did you do before this happended?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like a simple typo in the mentioned file name, as it is required to end with `.list` to be recognized as software sources list by `apt`.

To fix this, I suggest you rename the file and correct the extension with the command

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.lis /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
```

Comment: Also, read `man 5 sources.list` or http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/yakkety/en/man5/sources.list.5.html

Comment: Thanks Byte Commander, Your answer has resolved the problem

Comment: @ChristianNyembo If this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it to mark your question as solved. See https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Or with less typing by exploiting Bash’s brace expansion: `sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.lis{,t}`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error by running an `apt update` after following the commands given in Sublime's website. In my case, the wrong extension was `.listecho`. However the file `sublime-text.list`, which has the correct extension, did exist as well, and both files had the same content. So, it was safe to delete the one ending in `.listecho`.

In short, if you get this after installing a program, check if there is a `foo.list` as well, so that you can delete the one with the wrong name.